# manually changing alembic's HEAD position

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

An alembic migration that I ran recently errored out prematurely for system-related reasons. I had to cancel out and complete the migration manually. Now alembic is insisting that the migration has not been run.

I'd like to change the Alembic head position manually so that it believes that the migration has been completed. Is there a way to manually do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `alembic stamp`:

```
alembic stamp <revision>
```

Answer (score 10):

Delete (or move to another folder) the specific migration file (in `migrations/versions` folder).  The head will automatically revert to the most recent remaining migration.

Using `stamp` will set the db version value to the specified revision; not alter the `head` revision number.

Based on your question, the original answer will resolve your issue.  However it does not affect the head position as the title of the question states.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer does not change the `head` revision.